# PHP array save elements in variable

Tags: php, arrays, string, element

I have an array that looks like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>How can i get the firstName values from this array? its easy with
  print_r, <strong>but I want individual values</strong></p>
            [1] => How can i get the firstName values from this array? its easy with
  print_r, <strong>but I want individual values</strong>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>You can do:</p>
            [1] => You can do:
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>Since your array contains objects eg <code>stdClass</code>, you need to use <code>-&gt;</code> like shown above.</p>
            [1] => Since your array contains objects eg <code>stdClass</code>, you need to use <code>-&gt;</code> like shown above.
        )

)
```

how can i save the [1] values of every element in a string variable. What i want to get is

```
How can i get the firstName values from this array? its easy with
  print_r, <strong>but I want individual values</strong> You can do: Since your array contains objects eg <code>stdClass</code>, you need to use <code>-&gt;</code> like shown above.
```

---

**Update**: Well the array i have in the beginning is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>try this</p>

<pre><code>foreach($x as $val)
{
echo $val-&gt;firstName;
}
</code></pre>

    [1] => <p>Since you have an array of objects, you can either access each object by the array index or loop through the array to get each seperate object.</p>

<p>Once you have the object it self, you can simply access the first name property of the object.</p>

<p>Example of looping:</p>

<pre><code>foreach ( $array as $object ) {
echo $object-&gt;firstname;
}
</code></pre>

<p>Where $array is the variable containing your array.</p>

<p>Example of accessing via array index:</p>

<pre><code>echo $array[0]-&gt;firstname;
</code></pre>

<p>OR </p>

<pre><code>$obj = $array[0];
echo $obj-&gt;firstname;
</code></pre>

    [2] => <p>Try this (assume <code>$a</code> is your array):</p>

<pre><code>echo $a[0]-&gt;firstname;
</code></pre>

    [3] => <blockquote>
  <p>How can i get the firstName values from this array? its easy with
  print_r, <strong>but I want individual values</strong></p>
</blockquote>

<p>You can do:</p>

<pre><code>foreach($yourArray as $val){
  echo $val-&gt;firstName;
}
</code></pre>

<p>Since your array contains objects eg <code>stdClass</code>, you need to use <code>-&gt;</code> like shown above.</p>

)
```

and it's named answerstack then i use:

```
for($j=0;$j<$answerscnt;$j++){

    preg_match_all("#<p>(.*?)</p>#is",$answerstack[$j],$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($matches as $item){
        $answerstack[$j]=$item[1]." ";
    }

}
```

**what i want to accomplish is to remove `<code>` tags and the text between them from the first array but what i get is**

```
Array
(
    [0] => try this 
    [1] => OR  
    [2] => Try this (assume <code>$a</code> is your array): 
    [3] => Since your array contains objects eg <code>stdClass</code>, you need to use <code>-&gt;</code> like shown above. 
)
```

Comment: are you actually trying to remove all occurances of `<p>...</p>` from a string with regular expressions?

Comment: no that's what i'm trying to keep

Comment: maybe you should edit your question to reflect what you really want to achieve.

Comment: thanks i guess my question wasn't clear enough sorry for that i edited again. I want to remove the text between code tags too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the result of a `preg_match_all('#<p>(.*)</p>#sU')` and you are trying to remove all `<p>` paragraphs.

Here is another approach:

```
$text = preg_replace('#<p>(.*)</p>#isU', '\1 ', $text);
```

---

Here is a solution for the edited question. This code replaces all `<code>` tags and everything in between with an empty string:

```
// iterate over each element in $answerstack
foreach ($answerstack as &$text){
    // remove all '<code>' from $answerstack
    $text = preg_replace('#<code>(.*)</code>#isU', '', $text);
}
```

Comment: that was really close i actually want only the <p></p> and remove all te <code></code>

Comment: that just removes the code tabs not the text between them sorry i wasn't clear from the beginning

Comment: man thanks a lot that was really great stuff. Thanks for your life saving help

Answer (score 1):

```
 $var = "";
 foreach($ext_array as $temp)
     $var .= $temp[1] . ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($your_array as $item){
    echo $item[1]." ";
}
```